# Integrate command doesn't give the result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Subscript[σ, rr][r_, θ_] = 
  Subscript[K, 1]/(2 Sqrt[2 π r])
    Cos[θ/2] (3 - Cos[θ]);
Subscript[σ, θθ][r_, θ_] = 
  Subscript[K, 1]/(2 Sqrt[2 π r])
    Cos[θ/2] (1 + Cos[θ]);
Subscript[σ, rθ][r_, θ_] = 
  Subscript[K, 1]/(2 Sqrt[2 π r]) Cos[θ/2] Sin[θ];
Subscript[u, rr][r_, θ_] = 
  Subscript[K, 1]/(4 μ)
    Sqrt[(r/(
    2 π))][(2 κ - 1) Cos[θ/2] - Cos[(3 θ)/2]];
Subscript[u, θθ][r_, θ_] = 
  Subscript[K, 1]/(4 μ)
    Sqrt[(r/(
    2 π))][-(2 κ + 1) Sin[θ/2] + 
     Sin[(3 θ)/2]];
Subscript[ϵ, rr][r_, θ_] = 
  D[Subscript[u, rr][r, θ], r];
Subscript[ϵ, θθ][r_, θ_] = 
  Subscript[u, rr][r, θ]/r + 
   1/r D[Subscript[u, θθ][r, θ], θ];
Subscript[ϵ, rθ][r_, θ_] = (1/2)[
   1/r D[Subscript[u, rr][r, θ], θ] + 
    D[Subscript[u, θθ][r, θ], r] - 
    Subscript[u, θθ][r, θ]/r];
ω[r_, θ_] = (1/2)[
   Subscript[σ, rr][r, θ] Subscript[ϵ, rr][
      r, θ] + 
    Subscript[σ, θθ][
      r, θ] Subscript[ϵ, θθ][
      r, θ] + 
    2 Subscript[σ, rθ][
      r, θ] Subscript[ϵ, rθ][r, θ]];
Subscript[ω, rr][r_, θ_] = 
  1/2 Subscript[σ, rr][r, θ] Subscript[ϵ, rr][
    r, θ];
Subscript[ω, θθ][r_, θ_] = 
  1/2 Subscript[σ, θθ][
    r, θ] Subscript[ϵ, θθ][r, θ];
Subscript[ω, rθ][r_, θ_] = 
  Subscript[σ, rθ][r, θ] Subscript[ϵ, 
    rθ][r, θ];
Subscript[J, 1] = 
  Integrate[
    Subscript[ω, rr][
      r, θ] Cos[θ], {θ, -Pi, Pi}, 
    Assumptions -> r > 0] + 
   Integrate[
    Subscript[ω, θθ][
      r, θ] Cos[θ], {θ, -Pi, Pi}, 
    Assumptions -> r > 0] + 
   Integrate[
    Subscript[ω, rθ][
      r, θ] Cos[θ], {θ, -Pi, Pi}, 
    Assumptions -> r > 0];
```

This is the code I wrote into a Mathematica 11 script, but the result is exactly the same as the code I wrote, i.e. the Integrate command isn't actually performing the integral. Perhaps it might be something to do with trying to perform an integral based on functions that use other functions for their definitions?

Comment: The definition of `Subscript[\[Omega], rr][r, \[Theta]]`?

Comment: Each of the functions there is defined in terms of another group of functions. I'll see if I can get all the code into the next comment :)

Comment: @Damien Please do not put code in comments; instead [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/136338/edit) your question to include any needed information.

Comment: I've changed the question now.

Comment: `Subscript[u, rr][r, \[Theta]]` gives, `Subscript[K, 1]/(4 \[Mu])`, therefore when `Subscript[\[Epsilon], rr][r, \[Theta]]` derivates this to `r`, the result is zero.

Comment: @Feyre what do you mean? u_rr(r,theta) isn't just K1/4mu, I don't know where you get that from :S

Comment: @DamienClarke I suspect that your expressions got severely garbled when you copy / pasted them, so when we try to evaluate them, they are not what you intended anymore. I also suspect that you may be using `[ ]` improperly. Square brackets should only be used to delimit arguments of functions; you should probably use `( )` instead if your intention is to modify the order of evaluation (see e.g. in the definition of `Subscript[ϵ, rθ][r_, θ_]`).

Comment: It seems @MarcoB is correct, the issue is simply that you need to replace several square brackets with round ones. The excessive use of `Subscript` made this difficult to make out.

Comment: @MarcoB was indeed correct! Thank you! :) Also, my apologies Feyre, but the use of subscript is unavoidable in the work I'm doing - if I could only work out how to get the comments to show the actual code rather than longhand, I would've used that! :)